# how to prepare the data for two way Anova

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, descriptive-statistics

I have this data
[image]

I have to prepare this data to fit two way Anova test, so that the fall has to be the dependent variable, and the age group and gender are the dependent variable.
my table is

[image]

I do not know how to fill the table with numbers
my  try is

[image]

Is this correct?

I am new in the statistic field,
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not know what is hard to be understood,  the data is provided, need to prepare it for two way anova, fall, is dependent, while age group and gender is independent variables.